# how can i pass the the conditional phrase value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i pass the value in java script function. if i have value something like below ?

I have some php value like this

```
<?php $dataset = "{"label":"Server","value" : "40"},{"label":"Hypervisor","value" : "40"},{"label":"AD","value" : "40"},{"label":"vCenter - permissions","value" : "40"},{"label":"vCenter - maintenance","value" : "40"},{"label":"Resource Pool/datastore migration","value" : "40"},{"label":"vm - reboot","value" : "40"},{"label":"test1","value" : "40"},{"label":"VM","value" : "40"},{"label":"test3","value" : "40"},{"label":"Host modification","value" : "40"},{"label":"Host test","value" : "40"},{"label":"vCenter - Resource Pool (RP) modification","value" : "40"},{"label":"test 2","value" : "40"},{"label":"test 3","value" : "40"}"; ?>
```

I'm trying to pass this value in javascript function but im getting error ? how can i solve this ?

```
function somthing(<?php echo $dataset  ?>){
}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: put `var dataset = <?php echo  $dataset ; ?>;` inside your `somthing()` function.

Comment: Your quotes are causing the problem. You need to escape them like so: `<?php $dataset = "{\"label\":\"Server\",\"value\" : \"40\"},..."; ?>`. And in order to pass an argument to a function, you need to do it on the function call, not the function declaration. It should be like `somthing(<?=$dataset?>); function somthing(param){...}`

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to make it valid syntax before passing it anywhere

Comment: Even the line that sets `$dataset =`  the incorrect i.e. _WONT COMPILE_  Please annotate your questions with working code, otherwise we will just keep picking you up on silly mistakes.

Comment: That error message comes with a LINE NUMBER. What is the line number and what line of your code (that you have shown us) is the error on.

Comment: @blex Simply wrapping that line in single quotes would do the job. KISS

Comment: can you please give me the demo how can i over come with this @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

First your data definition is wrong, as there are more than one objects in that javscript it needs wrapping in `[{},{},...]` to make that valid javascript.

I decided it would be easier, and possibly more flexible to load that dataset data into a seperate javascript variable. I also echoed out each line seperately as I think that make be easier to read/debug

Then its quite easy from there, I shortened the `dataset` to make it easier to read the answer without removing any of its complexity ( or so I believe )

```
$dataset = '[{"label":"Server","value" : "40"},{"label":"Hypervisor","value" : "40"}]';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "var dataset = $dataset;";
echo 'function somthing(dataset){';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
```

I would like to assume you were creating the `$dataset` using `json_encode($someArray)` but in that case it would not have been wrong.

Can I suggest you look at manual pages for [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)